# JsonNode remove empty nodes

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonnode

I have a Dynamic JsonNode without POJO like this:

```
{
"Patient": {
        "Addresses": {},
        "Phones": {},
        "Faxes": {},
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "Test",
        "DateOfBirth": "5/5/1945 12:00:00 AM",
        "Allergies": {},
        "AdditionalInformation": {}
    },
    "Caregiver": [
        {
            "Addresses": {},
            "Phones": {},
            "Faxes": {},
            "AdditionalInformation": {}
        }
    ],
    "Physician": [
        {
            "Addresses": {},
            "Phones": {},
            "Faxes": {},
            "ContactPhone": {},
            "ContactFax": {},
            "Facility": {
                "Addresses": {},
                "Phones": {},
                "Faxes": {},
                "ContactPhone": {},
                "ContactFax": {}
            },
            "AdditionalInformation": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to remove empty objects '{}' from the JSON, such that the response looks like this:

```
{
"Patient": {
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "Test",
        "DateOfBirth": "5/5/1945 12:00:00 AM",
    },
    "Caregiver": [],
    "Physician": []
}
```

If all the objects within JSON arrays are empty, then need to remove them.

I tried with ObjectMapper from Jackson, but no luck.

```
 public static JsonNode stripEmpty(JsonNode node) {
        Iterator<JsonNode> it = node.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode child = it.next();
            if (child.isObject() && child.isEmpty(null))
                it.remove();
            else
                stripEmpty(child);
        }
        return node;
    }
```

I tried above code and it returned as:

```
 "Patient": {
        "FirstName": "Test",
        "LastName": "Test",
        "DateOfBirth": "5/5/1945 12:00:00 AM"
    },
    "Caregiver": [
        {}
    ],
    "Physician": [
        {
            "Facility": {}
        }
    ]
```

Comment: check sub Objects and Arrays with `!=null` and `.isEmpty()` and `!=0` and `""(string null)`.

Comment: will it work for json array like 'Caregiver' is this case, where all the child objects are empty

Comment: check jsonArray like this `jsonArray.length()!=0`